# NIS Installs but is not in /etc/init.d

Tags: system-installation

I am trying to install NIS on a 32 bit Ubuntu 14.04 version.
I installed portmap and nis, and the system thinks they are OK:

```
rjc@slater:/etc/init.d$ sudo apt-get install portmap nis
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Note, selecting 'rpcbind' instead of 'portmap'
nis is already the newest version.
rpcbind is already the newest version.
0 to upgrade, 0 to newly install, 0 to remove and 115 not to upgrade.
```

after setting up config files (e.g., yp.config), I tried to start the NIS service using:

```
/etc/init.d/nis start
```

but nis is not there:

```
rjc@slater:/etc/init.d$ ls -al /etc/init.d/nis
ls: cannot access /etc/init.d/nis: No such file or directory
```

What step am I missing?

Comment: Are you sure the script name `nis` is correct ? Couldn't be `yp` or something else ?

Comment: @Pyrophorus Unfortunately yp is not there either, nor is portmap. Using find I can see /usr/share/nis, but I don't think that is what I am looking for

Answer (score 0):

Its uses upstart and it is in /etc/init/

look at this

https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/154656/etc-init-d-nis-missing-on-ubuntu